# How to authenticate against my end points with passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, session-cookies

I have set up the spotify passport strategy with a mongo db to save the user profile, access and refresh tokens. But apart from the initial auth route and then the callback url, do I need to pass passport.authenticate as a callback to every route? Or am I supposed to have a custom middleware that checks if the cookie-session module still has req.user on the request? I see these as two possibilities. Which is the correct one? I know that on the cookie side, it will eventually expire and the /auth route will need to be called again.

I have made a middleware function that checks the user property of the request object. But am not sure how to test it. Perhaps reducing the cookie expiration time and check req.user is false.

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id)
        .then((user) => {
            done(null, user);
        });
});

passport.use(new SpotifyStrategy({
    clientID: keys.spotifyClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.spotifyClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/spotify/callback',
    proxy: true
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

    const spotifyId = profile.id
    const name = profile.displayName
    const email = profile.emails[0].value

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ spotifyId: profile.id });

    if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
    }

    const user = await new User({ spotifyId, name, accessToken, refreshToken}).save();

    done(null, user);
}));

Check the cookie middleware:
```

```
module.exports = isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {

if (req.user) {
    return next();
}

return res.redirect('/auth/spotify');
}
```

```
Example route:
```

```
module.exports = (app) => {

app.get('/api/spotify/playlists', passport.authenticate('spotify'), 
  (req, res) => {

console.log('got here')
console.log(req.user);

 //return playlists
});
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `middleware` which will check if the user is `authenticated` or not, and add that `middleware` to your `routes`.

Passport runs `deserializeUser` everytime a request is called, and it stores the authenticated user in `req.user`. The `middleware` will check if `req.user` exists, and if it exits it means the user is `logged in` and `authenticated`, and the request can be allowed to proceed.

You dont need to use `passport.authenticate('spotify')` with every request, you only need it at the time of `login`( or `registration`).

Middleware can be added like this:

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}

app.get('/api/spotify/playlists', isAuthenticated, 
  (req, res) => {

console.log('got here')
console.log(req.user);

 //return playlists
});
```

i hope this works out for you.

Comment: thanks, that helps me a lot. I do have `deserializeUser` and `serializeUser` , so great to know I can use that middleware function to check authentication on each route.